# conectar aplicacion de escritorio a una base de datos de un hosting? (somee)

Tags: c#

he desarrollado una aplicación de escritorio con una base de datos local y deseo colocar la base de datos en un hosting (somee).bajo los datos que me proporciona la pagina, puedo acceder por sqlserver pero al colocar los mismos datos en el App.config me sale un error que dice "Palabra clave no admitida" y me menciona el server name al que quiero acceder, les dejo como esta mi string de conexión gracias de antemano.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="BASEDEDATOSCadenaConexion"
      connectionString="BASEDEDATOS.mssql.somee.com;Initial Catalog=BASEDEDATOS;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=ABC;Password=123"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: esa cadena de conexion no parece correcta.. no falta database? o algo adelante de esa base de datos?

Comment: porque quieres hacer esto? no es para nada recomendado, sabes que expones la db para que cualquiera pueda vulnerarla? no se expone NUNCA la db directo a internet, quizas si fuera el acceso por una VPN ahi seria diferente, pero sino lo que debe crear son servicios web que alojar en el hosting y desde la app winform consumir esos servicios

Comment: Y ademas, todo lo que dice leandro...

Comment: Ya regañaron al OP, bien podríamos decirle también que MSSQL permite habilitar SSL en las conexiones.

Comment: en primer lugar grasias por sus comentarios me retroalimentan mucho y lo que estoy queriendo hacer es a modo de prueba, mi intencion es poner la base de datos en algun hosting ya sea azure etc para que la aplicación de escritorio pueda trabajar sin necesidad de red local, me ayudaría mucho si me pueden decir que opciones hay para lograr eso sin descuidar el tema de la seguridad.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba la siguiente:

```
    <add name="BASEDEDATOSCadenaConexion" connectionString="Data Source=nombreservidor o ip;Initial Catalog=BASEDEDATOS;User ID=ABC; Password=123"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Estas olvidando en la cadena la palabra clave **Data Source** (claro está que puedes usar tambien: Server, Address, Addr o Network Address. Puedes revisar la doc oficial:  [Connection string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8)) y falla el intento de conexión porque esta no tiene un valor por defecto, o sea, sí o sí debes especificarla.

Si te funcionó no olvides dejarme como mejor respuesta